# how to remove image in WF7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a list of images i add an icon button to remove the image when it was selected, what code must i put to remove the content  image i create a folder of pic called Images

```
List<Data> datasource = new List<Data>() 
        {
            new Data()
            {Text = "Chrysanthemum",ImageUri= "/Ima/Chrysanthemum.jpg"},
            new Data()
            {Text="Desert", ImageUri="/Ima/Desert.jpg"},
            new Data()
            {Text="Hydrangeas", ImageUri="/Ima/Hydrangeas.jpg"},
            new Data()
            {Text="Jellyfish", ImageUri="/Ima/Jellyfish.jpg"},
            new Data()
            {Text="Koala",ImageUri="/Ima/Koala.jpg"},
            new Data()
            {Text="Lighthouse", ImageUri ="/Ima/Lighthouse.jpg"},
            new Data()
            {Text="Penguins",ImageUri="/Ima/Penguins.jpg"},
            new Data()
            {Text="Tulips",ImageUri="/Ima/Tulips.jpg"}
        };
        this.listBox.ItemsSource = datasource;

     private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (listbox.selectedItem!= null)

          ................
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get clear whet you need. But
If you need remove item from list:

1. Make `datasource` as `ObservableCollection` and set it as member of class.
2. Remove item from `datasource`

If you need just remove image from item.

1. Take Data item from `selectedItem`
2. Set `ImageUri` null. (`Data` should implement `INotifyPropertyChange`. or it should inherit from `DependencyObject` and `ImageUri` should be DependencyProperty)

but to my mind you should use there `Triggers` for solve it.

> i create a folder of pic called Images

I didn't get it. what do you need exactly?

Comment: i would like  to create a list of picture gallery and when the picture is selected i remove the pic selected from this list